# Google Map Fragment within Scoll View - moving the view

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have a problem with a Map Fragment in my app.

I have a Scroll View of an event which includes the Map from Google. I want to move it, just as I would move my view in a google map. This works, however, whenever I go up and down I sometimes also scroll the view, which creates unpleasure user experience. How I could fix it?

Here is the layout xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.mysampleapp.EventCreationActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/content_event_view">

<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/space12"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

       Bunch of buttons etc here

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thank you in advance for any piece of advise!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `ScrollView` from view completely.

Right now some of touch events are dispatched by `ScrollView` - this is the reason why `SupportMapFragment` sometimes behaves strangely.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.mysampleapp.EventCreationActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/content_event_view">

<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/space12"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

       Bunch of buttons etc here

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I know, the problem is that the ScrollView MUST be there, as there are so many things, that have to be scrolled to be displayed all.

Comment: @GrzegorzBrzęczyszczykiewicz Nested scrollable containers are anti-pattern in android. You could e.g. replace scrollview by viewpager - one page with map and second page with buttons. Could you please describe how scrolling in your example should work? I am asking when map should dispatch touch events before scrollview?

Comment: Basically we start with a view of the event (have data on top) then as we move on we have a map, then we have further description, and at the bottom the "join" button. But it is too much to fit in in one screen. We wanted to have it in one activity, without having to switch the map to a different activity.